# Strange behavior of Apache with a ssl certificate while DNS are propagating

Tags: debian, ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

Is there anywhere a cache for certificates for **apache 2.4** under **Debian 9** ?

While DNS are propagating on an hosting, I sometimes get wrong certificate (the one of the first hosting of the server in alphanumerical sorting)...

I'm asking myself if this could come from a bad configuration on my side, I'm using **certbot-auto** program from let's encrypt under Debian 9.

The strange thing is that reload often succeeds while first click on the site in google search often shows warning about the security of the website, like if there were different behavior of apache regarding the origin of the request.

I'm sure that the request that fails comes to my server since the certificate shown as wrong is one of my server.

The message sent by Chrome is **NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID**

If I ping the domain from another server I always get the good IP, while if I "wget" the first page of the site from another server, sometimes I get the same error as Chrome in wget command.

Trying regenerate the certificate and/or reloading/restarting apache did not help.

Comment: This looks more like you sometimes access the wrong IP address because the DNS changes are still propagating. And at the wrong IP address is of course not the certificate you expect. There is no certificate cache for leaf certificates but there is a DNS cache in the  browser, i.e. it will not do a new DNS lookup for each request.

Comment: Thank you, I probably found the origin of the issue : it could be a bug in certbot that made a double apache conf to be written in the same file...